# Check to see if a variable exists in an array

Tags: php, mysql

I have an array and I am trying to see if it contains a certain value that is represented by a variable. The value will always be numeric The array is created from a MySQL select query

Variable:

```
$_SESSION['id']
```

Array

```
$likes_row
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A solution is to use the `in_array()` function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

```
if(in_array($_SESSION['id'], $likes_row))
{
   //Array contains the value
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(in_array($_SESSION['id'], $likes_row)){
 echo "we have likes!";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
if(in_array($_SESSION['id'], $likes_row, TRUE))
{
    // found it, now do something
}
```